# Excel 2010: Delete contents of cell if value in B equals text

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

**Program: Excel 2010:**

**Question:**
If E6=text then delete the value of A6 in Cells B6:C100

Basically when text in E6 equals "text"  then match all instances where A6 is found in B6:C100 and delete contents.

```
|  A Name  |  B Contents  |  C Contents  |  D Contents  |  E Values  |  
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Angel   |  Basic       |  Angel       |  D Contents  |  Defined   |  
----------------------------------------------------------------------  
|  Zeus    |  Zeus        |  Angel       |  D Contents  |  Defined   |  
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the above, Angel in row C2 would be deleted.  Zeus in B3 would be deleted 
Below is the result:

```
|  A Name  |  B Contents  |  C Contents  |  D Contents  |  E Values  |  
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Angel   |  Basic       |              |  D Contents  |  Defined   |  
----------------------------------------------------------------------  
|  Zeus    |              |  Angel       |  D Contents  |  Defined   |  
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Conditional formatting is preferred as it is a non Macro enabled book.

{Edit} 
Perhaps a formula that could be similar to:  `if e6='text' then if B6:C100 contain A6 ""` so rather than deleting the cell contents it overwrites them with a "".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Modifying cell contents is not possible when using conditional formatting, but you could choose white fonts on white background if you just don't want to see the actual cell contents. Anything else would require a macro.

Comment: No, the cell contents are counted for results, but once E contains "text" then it cancels out the data count.  Rather than Ctrl+F to find/replace with "" (Space"), I'd much rather it in a formula or conditional formatting.  (which you stated (the latter) can not be done.

Comment: If you add a new column (which you would then count), it will be possible without a macro.

Answer (score 0):

If you can have your results on a separate worksheet, the best solution I can think of is to create another worksheet and use the following methods:

1. Copy and paste links of your contents into the new worksheet.
2. Use a formula like `=IF(Original!$A1=Original!B1,"",Original!B1)` but with the cells referencing your original sheet.
3. Just copy this formula for all your cells in `B2:C100`

When you finish, just hide your source data worksheet and it should work.  Easy non-VBA solution.